# Password Protecting an Excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to password protect an entire Excel file (same functionality as File > Protect Workbook > Encrypt with Password) using Python.

I have come across openpyxl and the protection features it offers (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protection.html) seems to fulfill this need. I have the following code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

test_spreadsheet = "test.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(test_spreadsheet)
wb.security.workbookPassword = "password"
```

However, I am getting the following error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'workbookPassword'

Does anyone have an idea of what is causing this AttributeError? I have printed the sheetnames from wb and that is correctly printing the tabs in my Excel document.

Answer (score 0):

For a default-constructed workbook, the `security` property is initialized by default:

[`self.security = DocumentSecurity()`](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/87153d1598b5fc7692472d20ec2b6ef153ddf478/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#workbook.py-69)

However, workbooks constructed by [reading a workbook](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/87153d1598b5fc7692472d20ec2b6ef153ddf478/openpyxl/reader/excel.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#excel.py-313) are not just default-constructed; they are also manipulated by a `Parser` object:

[`wb_part = _find_workbook_part(self.package)
 self.parser = WorkbookParser(self.archive, wb_part.PartName[1:], keep_links=self.keep_links)
 self.parser.parse()
 wb = self.parser.wb
 ...
 self.wb = wb`](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/87153d1598b5fc7692472d20ec2b6ef153ddf478/openpyxl/reader/excel.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#excel.py-150:153)

`Parser.init` does [default-construct a `Workbook`](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/87153d1598b5fc7692472d20ec2b6ef153ddf478/openpyxl/reader/workbook.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#workbook.py-35), but then overrides specific properties with those of the source document:

[`self.wb.security = package.workbookProtection`](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/87153d1598b5fc7692472d20ec2b6ef153ddf478/openpyxl/reader/workbook.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#workbook.py-75)

This means that for files that had no security settings, the imported workbook object has a value of `None` for its `security` property (and thus your error, as `None` clearly has no attribute `workbookPassword`).

Your solution is then to create a default [`WorkbookProtection()`](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/87153d1598b5fc7692472d20ec2b6ef153ddf478/openpyxl/workbook/protection.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#protection.py-25), assign it to the workbook, and then set the workbook password.

Answer (score 0):

As the Openpyxl document states "Workbook Protection
To prevent other users from *viewing hidden worksheets, adding, moving, deleting, or hiding worksheets, and renaming worksheets*, you can protect the structure of your workbook with a password."
It's not the same as  File > Protect Workbook > Encrypt with Password.
Also does not work with an existing workbook.

If you run the following code, and open the newly created book 'test.xlsx' you should see it will open without a password however you cannot do any of those actions in italics above unless you go to the 'changes' toolbar and click 'Protect Workbook' then enter the password.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

test_spreadsheet = "test.xlsx"

wb = Workbook()
wb.security.workbookPassword = 'password'
wb.security.lockStructure = True
wb.save(test_spreadsheet)
```

I don't believe openpyxl supports the option you want.